# Flutter- paint image in canvas

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to draw Image using the `CustomPaint` Class. Here I am using the  `RenderProxyBox` to draw the image and cover with one layer, and using `BlendMode.clear` I am removing the layer. However I want to do that for multi image.
If anyone has any idea please comment

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart: math' as math;
class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scratch Card',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Scratch Card'),
        ),
        body: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 500.0,
              height: 500.0,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ScratchCard(
                    cover: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FittedBox(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/bird.jpg',
                            repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    reveal: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                      child: Center(
                        child:
                            FittedBox(child: Image.asset('assets/flower.jpg')),
                      ),
                    ),
                    strokeWidth: 15.0,
                    finishPercent: 50,
                    onComplete: () => print('The card is now clear!'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScratchCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScratchCard({
    Key key,
    this.cover,
    this.reveal,
    this.strokeWidth = 25.0,
    this.finishPercent,
    this.onComplete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget cover;
  final Widget reveal;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final int finishPercent;
  final VoidCallback onComplete;

  @override
  _ScratchCardState createState() => _ScratchCardState();
}

class _ScratchCardState extends State<ScratchCard> {
  _ScratchData _data = _ScratchData();

  Offset _lastPoint = null;

  Offset _globalToLocal(Offset global) {
    return (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).globalToLocal(global);
  }

  double _distanceBetween(Offset point1, Offset point2) {
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(point2.dx - point1.dx, 2) +
        math.pow(point2.dy - point1.dy, 2));
  }

  double _angleBetween(Offset point1, Offset point2) {
    return math.atan2(point2.dx - point1.dx, point2.dy - point1.dy);
  }

  void _onPanDown(DragDownDetails details) {
    _lastPoint = _globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
  }

  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final currentPoint = _globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    final distance = _distanceBetween(_lastPoint, currentPoint);
    final angle = _angleBetween(_lastPoint, currentPoint);
    for (double i = 0.0; i < distance; i++) {
      _data.addPoint(Offset(
        _lastPoint.dx + (math.sin(angle) * i),
        _lastPoint.dy + (math.cos(angle) * i),
      ));
    }
    _lastPoint = currentPoint;
  }

  void _onPanEnd(TapUpDetails details) {
    final areaRect = context.size.width * context.size.height;
    double touchArea = math.pi * widget.strokeWidth * widget.strokeWidth;
    double areaRevealed =
        _data._points.fold(0.0, (double prev, Offset point) => touchArea);
    print('areaRect $areaRect $areaRevealed');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onPanDown: _onPanDown,
      onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
      onTapUp: _onPanEnd,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          widget.reveal,
          _ScratchCardLayout(
            strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
            data: _data,
            child: widget.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ScratchCardLayout extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  _ScratchCardLayout({
    Key key,
    this.strokeWidth = 25.0,
    @required this.data,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          child: child,
        );

  final Widget child;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final _ScratchData data;

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _ScratchCardRender(
      strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
      data: data,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _ScratchCardRender renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..data = data;
  }
}

class _ScratchCardRender extends RenderProxyBox {
  _ScratchCardRender({
    RenderBox child,
    double strokeWidth,
    _ScratchData data,
  })  : assert(data != null),
        _strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        _data = data,
        super(child);

  double _strokeWidth;
  _ScratchData _data;

  set strokeWidth(double strokeWidth) {
    assert(strokeWidth != null);
    if (_strokeWidth == strokeWidth) {
      return;
    }
    _strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  set data(_ScratchData data) {
    assert(data != null);
    if (_data == data) {
      return;
    }
    if (attached) {
      _data.removeListener(markNeedsPaint);
      data.addListener(markNeedsPaint);
    }
    _data = data;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  @override
  void attach(PipelineOwner owner) {
    super.attach(owner);
    _data.addListener(markNeedsPaint);
  }

  @override
  void detach() {
    _data.removeListener(markNeedsPaint);
    super.detach();
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      context.canvas.saveLayer(offset & size, Paint());
      context.paintChild(child, offset);
      Paint clear = Paint()..blendMode = BlendMode.clear;
      _data._points.forEach((point) =>
          context.canvas.drawCircle(offset + point, _strokeWidth, clear));
      context.canvas.restore();
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get alwaysNeedsCompositing => child != null;
}

class _ScratchData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Offset> _points = [];

  void addPoint(Offset offset) {
    _points.add(offset);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Expected:

[image: expected]
[image: expected-2]

Comment: The problem has been solved using ``ImageShader``

Comment: masking issue solved.

Comment: Can you please reduce the example so it's easier to read? Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us how did you implement the [`ImageShader`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageShader-class.html) from your code?